# Edit your communities button doesn't appear on Stack Exchange's homepage

Tags: bug, stackexchange.com, communities-list

If you try to edit your favorite communities on the [Stack Exchange homepage](https://stackexchange.com/), the edit button doesn't appear. It does if you try to edit them while actually in a community.

[image: Screenshots of the bug]

Comment: Not a bug, reasoning explained in the linked dupe.